# apache global basic auth

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

I have apache web server with several virtualhosts

I would like all of them be behind basic authorization (AuthType Basic)

But - it seems the Auth derective works only for `<Location>` and `<Directory>` (inside Virtualhost section)

is there a way to set basic auth globally for **all** virtual hosts at once ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any `<Directory>` or `<Location>` set in global configuration (httpd.conf or apache2.conf on Debian) will apply for all VirtualHosts, as a **global** configuration is shared *by definition*.

It's quite hard to share a `<Directory>` location, as you may have different `DocumentRoot` for your VirtualHosts. But `<Location />` is a good target, all your Virtualhosts will have a '/' url.

So, if you put that in a `<Location />` in the global definition it will work, unless a `<Location />` on one VirtualHost is using some directive to remove the Auth.