# apache basic auth across multiple virtualhosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost, basic-authentication

I have a few staging sites as virtual hosts on a server, plus a couple of public-facing virtual host sites.  The stating sites are all under a single directory (e.g., `/var/www/staging-sites/[site-document-root]`).

Up to now I've been configuring HTTP Basic Auth for each virtual host, but it seems like there should be a way to do it once for all of them.

The question "[apache global basic auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272134/apache-global-basic-auth?newreg=1b9306b1f6aa4f578770893efb5e3882)" indicates that I could place Basic Auth directives in a `<Directory /var/www/staging-sites>` container in the main apache config file, but doing so doesn't cause the browser to prompt for credentials.

Here's the output of `tail -n 7 /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/staging-sites/">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication Required"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /var/www/staging-sites/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

- I've verified that /var/www/staging-sites/.htpasswd exists, and that the site foo.mydomain.com uses the Document Root /var/www/staging-sites/foo.
- I've restarted apache to ensure the new config gets loaded.

However, when I open http://foo.mydomain.com, the site is displayed without prompting for Basic Auth credentials.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You indeed should configure the basic auth requirement for each virtual host separately and thus explicitly. But since you use an _absolute_ path to the `.htpasswd` file you can use the same file for _all_ virtual hosts. That reduces the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The problem was this section in the virtualhost configuration itself:

```
<Directory /var/www/staging-sites/foo>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Apparently all the virtualhosts were created with an equivalent configuration. As might be expected, `Require all granted` in the virtualhost config outdoes `Require valid-user` in the global config.

Removing that line allows the Basic Auth, as configured above, to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leave `Require all granted` but add `Satisfy all`

Comment: (Please elaborate your qnswer a bit more. Otherwise, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).